# Way to check for duplicates before writing into a file?

Tags: go

So I wrote a small script that takes text files as an input, reads every line and tries to validate it as an email. If it passes, it writes the line into a new ('clean') file, if it doesn't pass, it strips it of spaces and tries to validate it again. Now, if it passes this time, it writes the line into a new file and if it fails, it ignores the line.

Thing is, such as it is, my script may write duplicate emails into the output files. How should I go around that and check for duplicates present in the output file before writing?

Here's the relevant code:

```golang
// create reading and writing buffers
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(r)
    writer := bufio.NewWriter(w)

    for scanner.Scan() {
        email := scanner.Text()

        // validate each email
        if !correctEmail.MatchString(email) {
            // if validation didn't pass, strip and lowercase the email and store it
            email = strings.Replace(email, " ", "", -1)
            // validate the email again after cleaning
            if !correctEmail.MatchString(email) {
                // if validation didn't pass, ignore this email
                continue
            } else {
                // if validation passed, write clean email into file
                _, err = writer.WriteString(email + "\r\n")
                if err != nil {
                    return err
                }
            }

        } else {
            // if validation passed, write the email into file
            _, err = writer.WriteString(email + "\r\n")
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
        }

    }

    err = writer.Flush()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a Go built-in map as a set like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var emailSet map[string]bool = make(map[string]bool)

func emailExists(email string) bool {
    _, ok := emailSet[email]
    return ok
}

func addEmail(email string) {
    emailSet[email] = true
}

func main() {
    emails := []string{
        "duplicated@golang.org",
        "abc@golang.org",
        "stackoverflow@golang.org",
        "duplicated@golang.org", // <- Duplicated!
    }
    for _, email := range emails {
        if !emailExists(email) {
            fmt.Println(email)
            addEmail(email)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
duplicated@golang.org
abc@golang.org
stackoverflow@golang.org
```

You may try the same code at <kbd>[The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/yRbU8_TzlF)</kbd>.

Comment: That's perfect. I've edited my code to incorporate your solution and it's both elegant and teaching. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Create a type that implements `writer` then create a custom `WriteString`

Inside `WriteString` open the file where you store your emails, iterate over each email and save the new emails.

Comment: I wasn't able to follow your instructions based on what you said. Another solution based on maps worked though.