# Excluding duplicates in FindAllString regex

Tags: go

I've the below code, that is reading all `txt` files at the root directory, scan them for specific words basedon the given `regex` and report the words in the `regex` that are found in each file.
The issue I've is if a wod is mentioned more than ones (i.e. in different loctions in the file) it will be reported as much as it is appearing,I need to reort it as unique so excluding duplicates. for example in the `txt` file:

```
I'm an engineer not a doctor
really, I'm not a doctor
```

The word `doctor` is reported twice, while I need to get it as unique, ie. it is enough for me to know it is there in the file.
My code is:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "path/filepath"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    files, err := ioutil.ReadDir(".")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    p := []string{}
    p = append(p, "engineer")
    p = append(p, "doctor")
    p = append(p, "chemical (permit)")
    skills := strings.Join(p, "|")

    fmt.Println(skills)
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`(?i)` + skills)

    for _, file := range files {
        if strings.ToLower(filepath.Ext(file.Name())) == ".txt" {
            fmt.Println(file.Name())

            b, err := ioutil.ReadFile(file.Name()) // just pass the file name
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Print(err)
            }
            //fmt.Println(b) // print the content as 'bytes'

            str := string(b) // convert content to a 'string'
            matches := re.FindAllString(str, -1)
            fmt.Println(matches, len(matches))

            for _, j := range matches {
                fmt.Println(j)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does [Way to check for duplicates before writing into a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38816139/5728991) answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can transfrom your matches from a `[]string` to a `Set` using: https://godoc.org/github.com/golang-collections/collections/set

like so:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "path/filepath"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
    "github.com/golang-collections/collections/set"
)

func main() {
    files, err := ioutil.ReadDir(".")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    p := []string{}
    p = append(p, "engineer")
    p = append(p, "doctor")
    p = append(p, "chemical (permit)")
    skills := strings.Join(p, "|")

    fmt.Println(skills)
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`(?i)` + skills)

    for _, file := range files {
        if strings.ToLower(filepath.Ext(file.Name())) == ".txt" {
            fmt.Println(file.Name())

            b, err := ioutil.ReadFile(file.Name()) // just pass the file name
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Print(err)
            }
            //fmt.Println(b) // print the content as 'bytes'

            str := string(b) // convert content to a 'string'
            matches := re.FindAllString(str, -1)
            matchesSet := set.New(matches...)
            matchesSet.Do(func print(s string) {
              fmt.Println(s)
            }
            // fmt.Println(matches, len(matches))

            // for _, j := range matches {
            //     fmt.Println(j)
            // }
        }
    }
}
```